# ないとなると meaning in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Context: The protagonist is searching for a girl in his house, and since his house is really big he has yet to find her.

> ここまで捜していないとなると、後は道場か土蔵ぐらいなものだろう。

I don't understand this sentence.

ここまで=Until here
捜していない=Not looking for; Not searching
となると=If it's the case; If it comes to that
後は道場か土蔵ぐらいなものだろう。=After that, the dojo or the storehouse.

I don't understand why it's 捜していない.

> If I do not look until here, After that, the dojo or the storehouse.

But it does not make sense, does it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 「ここまで[捜]{さが}していないとなると、[後]{あと}は[道場]{どうじょう}か[土蔵]{どぞう}ぐらいなものだろう。」

In the phrase 「捜していない」 in this context,

> It is Person **A** who is 捜している (searching), and
>
> it is Person **B** who is いない (not there).

The above was your (only) mistake, but since it was a big one, it cost you the rest of the sentence.

One more thing.  「ここまで」 here means more like "to this degree", "as hard as this", etc.  It does not really mean "until here".

My own fairly literal TL:

> "If we searched this hard and still couldn't find her, that would mean that the remaining possibility would be either the dojo or the storehouse."

Your understanding of 「～～となると」 is just fine.  I just happened to use "that would mean" in my TL.

Answer (score 8):

The 捜していない of this sentence doesn't mean " Not looking for "  but  " I looked for but I couldn't find ". It's 捜して and (捜された人[the person who was looked for]が)いない.

Comment: Oh I see. I tought a verb in the ている form was either: -doing or a stative result from an action. 捜している can mean both then? Looked and found or Looking for?

Comment: I think 捜している is almost ている form but 捜していない is in both cases.