# Understanding ってなったら

Tags: grammar

> だが一般文芸、しかも新進気鋭の彩坂桜が書く**ってなったら**話題沸騰間違いなし……になるかもしれない

How should I understand the bold part? というなったら doesn’t sound right.

Comment: You know that って can also be と not just という, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since って is followed by a verb, it's a colloquial version of と, not という. So the sentence is the same as 彩坂桜が書くとなったら. For ～となる, see:

- [Meaning of verb+となる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47659/5010)
- [ないとなると meaning in a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30891/5010)
- [JLPT N1 Grammar となると / となれば](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-to-naru-to-nareba-meaning/)

> だが一般文芸、しかも新進気鋭の彩坂桜が書くってなったら話題沸騰間違いなし
> But when it comes to general literary arts, and up-and-coming Sakura Ayasaka writing one, it's sure to be a hot topic.